# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with external jars in java applet

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet

I have a Java applet which utilizes multiple external jars.  In Eclipse the project runs fine.  When it is exported and run embedded in a HTML file I get 22 run-time exceptions similar to..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    mil/dcgs/mdf/webservice/ddms/ingest/CatalogIngestService
```

..with various classes.  When I open the exported jar I see no .class files or any other traces from the external jar.

#### HTML

The HTML is:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>DIB Applet</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<applet 
    code="org.mitre.inception.Main.class" 
    archive="inception.jar" 
    WIDTH = "1020" 
    HEIGHT = "500">
Applet
</applet> 
</body> 
</html>
```

#### .classpath

My `.classpath` looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/jars/dcgs-util.jar"/>
    <!-- more jars removed for space reasons as they look the same as above -->
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: `<html>
<head>
 <title>DIB Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
 <applet code="org.mitre.inception.Main.class" archive="inception.jar"  WIDTH = "1020" HEIGHT = "500">Applet</applet>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Cool.  Glad you sorted it. :-)  I deleted the comment and added it as an answer.  Please mark it correct if it was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `classpath` mentions `dcgs-util.jar`. That should probably be listed in the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.  Perhaps something like:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>DIB Applet</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<applet 
    code="org.mitre.inception.Main.class" 
    archive="inception.jar,jars/dcgs-util.jar" 
    WIDTH = "1020" 
    HEIGHT = "500">
Applet
</applet> 
</body> 
</html>
```

That would be assuming `inception.jar` was in the same directory as the HTML, and that `dcgs-util.jar` is in the `jars` sub-directory of the dir. where the HTML is located.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the following classpath. I just changed the order of the jar files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/jars/dcgs-util.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>    
    <!-- more jars removed for space reasons as they look the same as above -->
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```